# Modifying width of outline in a pie chart in R--what is the equivalent of lwd parameter for pie()?

Tags: r

I'm using `base` R plotting functions to produce a pie chart and I want to change the line thickness of the outlines of each pie segment.  `?pie` seems to indicate that I can add optional graphic parameters, but adding `lwd=` does not appear to work.  Anyone have any clues as to how I might be able to do this.  I'm not yet proficient in producing pie charts in `ggplot`, and would like to stick with `base` R plotting (if possible).

```
library(RColorBrewer)

x1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(200, 100)) ##  generate data

row.names(x1) <- c("A", "B")

x1$pct <- round((x1$V1/sum(x1$V1))*100, 1)

lbls1 <- paste(row.names(x1), "-(",x1$pct, '%)', sep='') ## add some informative stuff

pie(x1$V1, labels=lbls1, col=tail(brewer.pal(3, 'PuBu'), n=2), 
           main=paste('My 3.1415'), cex=1.1, lwd= 3)
```

Notice `lwd=` does not increase line thickness like it would in other base plotting.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Did you read to the bottom of `?pie`? Most importantly, "Pie charts are a very bad way of displaying information." Heed this advice!! Regardless, it explicitly states the graphic parameters only affect the main title and labels

Comment: I hear ya alexwhan... The pie charts are by request.  I've got to pick and choose my battles with internal customers. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `polygon` and `lines` within `pie` does not pass `...` or `lwd`

```
...
polygon(c(P$x, 0), c(P$y, 0), density = density[i], angle = angle[i], 
        border = border[i], col = col[i], lty = lty[i])
    P <- t2xy(mean(x[i + 0:1]))
    lab <- as.character(labels[i])
    if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
        lines(c(1, 1.05) * P$x, c(1, 1.05) * P$y)
....
```

You can get around this by setting `par(lwd = 2)` (or whatever) outside and prior to your call to `pie`

i.e.

```
# save original settings
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(lwd = 2)
pie(x1$V1, labels=lbls1, col=tail(brewer.pal(3, 'PuBu'), n=2), 
  main=paste('My 3.1415'), cex=1.1)
```

[image]

```
par(lwd = 3)
```

[image]

```
# reset to original
par(opar)
```

Answer (score 8):

At the moment, the function inside `pie` that does the actual drawing is `polygon` and here is how it is called:

```
polygon(c(P$x, 0), c(P$y, 0), density = density[i], angle = angle[i], 
        border = border[i], col = col[i], lty = lty[i])
```

Notice there is no `lwd` argument and more critically no `...` argument to accept arguments that might not have been hard coded.

Create a new pie2 function. First type pie, copy the code and make a few changes:

```
pie2 <- 
   function (x, labels = names(x), edges = 200, radius = 0.8, clockwise = FALSE, 
             init.angle = if (clockwise) 90 else 0, density = NULL, angle = 45, 
             col = NULL, border = NULL, lty = NULL, main = NULL,  lwd=1,...) 

    {
       ................
     polygon(c(P$x, 0), c(P$y, 0), density = density[i], angle = angle[i], 
           border = border[i], col = col[i], lty = lty[i], lwd=lwd )
       .................

       }
  pie2(x1$V1, labels=lbls1, col=tail(brewer.pal(3, 'PuBu'), n=2), 
              main=paste('My 3.1415'), cex=1.1, lwd=5)
```